# Another variant of merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I was supposed to come with a more efficient variant of merge sort that avoids recursive allocation of arrays while using two mutually recursive methods. However, this one is not becoming a more efficient one since its running time slower than the usual one. Any advice would be appreciated

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82};
    System.out.println("begin with: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));
    System.out.println("------------------");

    mergesort1(array, array.length);

    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("end with: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static void mergesort1(int[] a, int last) {

    if (last > 1) {
        int l = (last / 2);
        int r = last - l;
        int[] leftArray = new int[l];
        int[] rightArray = new int[r];

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            leftArray[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int i = l; i < l + r; i++) {
            rightArray[i - l] = a[i];
        }
        mergesort1(rightArray, r);
        System.arraycopy(rightArray, 0, a, l, r);
        int[] t = new int[l];
        mergesort2(leftArray, l, t);
        System.arraycopy(t, 0, a, 0, l);
        merge(t, l, last, a);
        t = null;
    }
}

public static void mergesort2(int[] b, int last, int[] d) {
    if (last > 1) {
        int l = (last / 2);
        int r = last - l;
        int[] leftArray = new int[l];
        int[] rightArray = new int[r];
        int[] dArray = new int[r];
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, leftArray, 0, l);
        System.arraycopy(b, l, rightArray, 0, r);
        System.arraycopy(d, l, dArray, 0, r);
        mergesort1(leftArray, l);
        System.arraycopy(leftArray, 0, b, 0, l);
        mergesort2(rightArray, r, dArray);
        System.arraycopy(rightArray, 0, b, l, r);
        System.arraycopy(dArray, 0, d, l, r);
        merge(b, l, last, d);
    } else {
        d[0] = b[0]; // Trivial case
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] le, int l, int n, int[] a) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = l;
    int k = 0;
    int myTemp = 0;

    while ((i < l)) {
        if ((le[i] <= a[j]) || (a[j] == 0)) {
            if ((k < a.length)) {
                a[k] = le[i];
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            if ((k < a.length)) {
                int innerTemp = 0;
                if (myTemp == 0) {
                    a[k] = a[j];
                    innerTemp = 1;
                }
                j++;
                if (j == n) {
                    j--;
                    myTemp = 1;
                    if (innerTemp == 0) {
                        a[k] = le[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ((k < a.length)) {
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

*Updated
I have to tried to update the code according to the suggestion below and still it doesn't give out the correct result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82};
    System.out.println("begin with: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));
    System.out.println("------------------");

    mergesort(array, array.length);

    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("end with: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static void mergesort(int[] a, int size) {   
    if (size < 2) {
        return;
    }
    int[] b = new int[size];         
    mergesort1(a, b, 0, size-1);    

}

public static void mergesort1(int[] a, int[] b, int low, int end) {

    if ((end - low) == 1) 
    {
        return;                      
    }
    int mid = (low + end) / 2;
    mergesort1(a, b, low, mid);
    mergesort2(a, b, mid, end);       
    merge(b, a, low, mid, end);
}

public static void mergesort2(int[] a, int[] b, int low, int end) {
    if ((end - low) == 1) {            
        b[low] = a[low];             
        return;                      
    }
    int mid = (low + end) / 2;        
    mergesort1(a, b, low, mid);
    mergesort2(a, b, mid, end);       
    merge(a, b, low, mid, end);
}

public static void mergeArrays(int[] toSort, int[] tempArray, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = mid;
    int k = 0;
    int myTemp = 0;

    while ((i < mid)) {
        if ((tempArray[i] <= toSort[j]) || (toSort[j] == 0)) {
            if ((k < toSort.length)) {
                toSort[k] = tempArray[i];
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            if ((k < toSort.length)) {
                int innerTemp = 0;
                if (myTemp == 0) {
                    toSort[k] = toSort[j];
                    innerTemp = 1;
                }
                j++;
                if (j == high) {
                    j--;
                    myTemp = 1;
                    if (innerTemp == 0) {
                        toSort[k] = tempArray[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ((k < toSort.length)) {
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using lots of unnecessary `System.arraycopy`. You only have to use array copy once after the merge, to copy the merged array into the original array. And for passing your sub-arrays to the inner functions you just have to pass the start and end indices of the sub-arrays. There is no need to copy them into another array and pass those to the functions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid recursive allocation, do a one time allocation of the temp buffer, either in main() or in an entry function that calls one of the mutually recursive functions. The mutually recursive functions just generate indices and eliminate the need to copy back, while merge() does the actual merging. This partial example uses half closed intervals, first (low) and end for parameters.

```
void mergesort(int[] a, int size){   // entry function
    if(size < 2)
        return;
    int[] b = new int[size];         // allocate temp buffer just once
    mergesortatoa(a, b, 0, size);    // sort a
    delete[] b;                      // delete b
}

// merge sort from a to a
void mergesortatoa(int[] a, int[] b, int low, int end)
{
    if((end - low) == 1)             // if just 1 element
        return;                      //   return
    int mid = (low + end)/2          // or low + (end - low)/2
    mergesortatob(a, b, low, mid);
    mergesortatob(a, b, mid, end);
    merge(b, a, low, mid, end);
}

// merge sort from a to b
void mergesortatob(int[] a, int[] b, int low, int end)
{
    if((end - low) == 1){            // if just 1 element
        b[low] = a[low];             //   "mergesort" a to b
        return;                      //   return
    }
    int mid = (low + end)/2          // or low + (end - low)/2
    mergesortatoa(a, b, low, mid);
    mergesortatoa(a, b, mid, end);
    merge(a, b, low, mid, end);
}

// merge from x to y (no copy, just y[...] = x[...])
void merge(int[] x, int[] y, int low, int mid, int end)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid many copies by allocating a single array of the same size as the original and perform the merges alternatively to the other array.

When you get to tiny subarrays, the parity of the recursion depth will tell you if you need to merge in-place or to the other array.

```
38, 27, 43,  3,  9, 82
 -   -   -   -   -   -
====================== (in-place 0-1 and 3-4)
27, 38, 43,  3,  9, 82
 -   -   -   -   -   -
====================== (to copy, 0-2 and 3-5)
 -   -   -   -   -   -
27, 38, 43,  3,  9, 82
====================== (to original, 0-5)
 3,  9, 27, 38, 43, 82
 -   -   -   -   -   -
```